# MultiViewerFactory causing thicker edges on the second (and third, etc.) viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

My intention is to save some resources when loading the same model in multiple viewers by following [this guide](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/sharing-resources-among-multiple-viewers). However, it seems that `Autodesk.Viewing.MultiViewerFactory` is causing the second viewer showing thicker edges on the model:
[Thinker edges on second viewer caused by MultiViewerFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb5ih.png)

Actually, the problem also appears in the guide mentioned above if you look closely at the screen shots in that post. (notice the difference between the two smaller viewers)

If I create two separate viewers without using `Autodesk.Viewing.MultiViewerFactory`, the problem disappears. But this way I can't save resources when loading two same models.

Besides, there is still another smaller problem in both ways of creating multiple viewers: the cube on the upper right corner in the second viewer loses the text and detail and becomes dark, which also can be spotted in the screenshot in the post mentioned above.

Any configs am I missing or any ways to fix this? Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue with the MultiViewerFactory tool.

We have created a request to address a change in the functionality and it has been added to the backlog of the Viewer Team.

In the meantime, there are a few approaches you could take in order to optimize the performance and experience while using multiple instances:

- Use [selective loading](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-feature-selective-loading), so only what's necessary gets rendered on each instance
- [Skip properties db](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only) in instances where you don't need them (refer [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/mimicking-viewer-fit-view-without-properties-database) if you need selection or fit to view without properties db)
- Use [SVF2](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready) to optimize geometry (just know that it won't optimize geometry across Viewer instances)